# Domain point to different ip dependent on port requested

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a domain currently with an A record pointing to an Amazon EC2 instance ip. This works great. I am hosting a Minecraft server on a different network, therefore from a different public ip. Can I make it so that my domain will direct traffic on port 25565 (Minecraft port) to the public ip of the Minecraft server, and direct web traffic (ports 80 and 443) to the EC2 instance public ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a subdomain and point that to the Minecraft server, while pointing the root to your web server. For instance..

example.com —> 192.168.2.4 (web server)

minecraft.example.com —> 192.168.2.7 (minecraft server)

DNS by itself isn’t port-aware (with a somewhat exception of SRV records, which wouldn’t apply here).

Comment: Minecraft clients do consume `SRV` records in fact...